# Getting ConnectionStrings config settings from appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, asp.net-core-configuration

In my repository class, I have my Config object and looks like my connection string is under:

```
Config > Providers > Microsoft.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider > Data > ConnectionStrings.myConnectionString
```

This is what my `appsettings.json` looks like:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myConnectionString": details..."
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read `myConnectionString` as follows which is not working:

```
var cs = _config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings.myConnectionString").value;
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
For some reason, I'm not seeing `GetValue()` method. I'm using `ASP.NET Core 2.0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to lie in the string path you are passing to the GetSection() method. According to the [ASP.NET Core Configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) you should use "ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString" instead of "ConnectionStrings.myConnectionString".

Plus, if you wish to retrieve the value directly you may prefer to use the GetValue() method instead:

```
var cs = _config.GetValue("ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString", "");
```

If you prefer, you can also use the index notation as:

```
var cs = _config["ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString"];
```

But I honestly find the first approach more clean and elegant as the GetValue() method allows you to specify a default value in case the property is not found in the configuration.

Comment: Thank you! Using a colon fixed the issue. I also wanted to use the `GetValue()` method but for some reason, it's not available to me. See update in original post. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: The method lies in the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace. Are you using it? If not, then try and you should then be able to access it.

Comment: It's in that namespace but it's actually an extension via Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration API provides extension method for `IConfiguration` to simplify reading `ConnectionStrings` section:

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("myConnectionString");
```

[what it does is](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dc6fbde39f532bf154ee1eb02d8be08a0a1605e4/src/Config.Abstractions/ConfigurationExtensions.cs#L36) `return configuration?.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")?[name];`